# Stick PC failing to boot from USB, just reboots

Tags: windows-10

I have a 32bit windows 10 stick PC, which needs to be 64 bit for software I need to run. 
Have checked the CPU and it does support a 64 bit OS.

Using a existing windows 10 boot image (64bit) on a USB the PC just reboots, when forced to boot through advanced startup screen or bios. 
USB works and has been used on other machines before 
Even when forcing USB boot from bios, just reboots the device and takes me to sign in page

[image]
[image]

I would like to avoid having to use emulators to run the 64x software

Comment: I am going to guess your pc has a 32-bit UEFI shell, which means, you won’t be able to boot a 64-but is while in UEFI mode.  If the firmware doesn’t allow you to use a legacy mode then what you want isn’t possible

Comment: @Ramhound You're right and this early Bay Trails don't even have Legacy/CSM support. Ubuntu "found" a workaround by using a 32-bit bootloader in a 64-bit installer but for Windows there's no such workaround. This stick or MiniPCs were designed to run 32-bit Windows only.